# Channel Images and Matrix / Increment a variable/count within a matrix field?

Tags: ee2, matrix, variable, channel-images

Is there a possibility to increment a variable/count (something like "i++") within a matrix field so that the variable is incremented for each row with certain parameters?

The background is that I created a Matrix field to allow the user to reorder html elements. We use Channel Images to upload

I'm trying to achieve this in my template:

```
{my_matrix}

 {if cell_type == "image"}
 <!-- insert image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image"i++".jpg -->
   {exp:channel_images:images_static entry_id="{entry_id}"}
     <img src="{image:{i++}:url}">
   {/exp:channel_images:images_static"}
 {/if}

 {if cell_type == "text"}
   {text_from_matrix_cell}
 {/if}

{/my_matrix}
```

The html code is supposed to be looking like this:

```
<img src="image1.jpg">
<p>Text block 1…</p>
<img src="image2.jpg">
<p>Text block 2…</p>
<p>Text block 3…</p>
<img src="image3.jpg">
```

I tried it with a switch:

```
{my_matrix}

 {if cell_type == "image"}
   {exp:channel_images:images_static entry_id="{entry_id}"}
     <img src="{image:{switch'1|2|3|4|5'}:url}">
   {/exp:channel_images:images_static"}
 {/if}

 …

{/my_matrix}
```

The switch statement is working between matrix rows. However, it's alternating between matrix rows *whether the surrounding "if"-statement applies or not*. So instead of the desired result posted above, my actual html looks like this:

```
<img src="image1.jpg">
<p>Text block 1…</p>
<img src="image3.jpg">
<p>Text block 2…</p>
<p>Text block 3…</p>
<img src="image6.jpg">
```

I couldn't think of a way to solve this with php either. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
{matrix}
  {exp:channel_images:images_static entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    {image:{element_count}}
  {/exp:channel_images:images_static}
{/matrix}
```

({element_count} is the matrix field where you can choose the #-th image).